# How can I queue multiple jobs, but limit it to run 5 at a time, using Bash

Tags: bash, autosys

I have an text file that holds a list of jobs to process. It could process them all at once, but it overloads computer resources and some jobs fail. It could also process one line at a time, but the overall processing time is too long.

My customer is asking us to process 5 at a time to see if we can speed up processing time without missing jobs along the way. I feel like this is possible and likely pretty easy, but my brain is stuck on it and I can't figure it out.

Each job is on one row of the text file. Is there a way to load a list of jobs to run, but limit it to running 5 at a time?

Answer (score 1):

this should execute in the manner you are looking for. I have not tested it though. It will work only on BASH.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a jobs < list_of_jobs.txt
total_number_of_jobs=$( wc -l list_of_jobs.txt | awk '{print $1}' )
i=0;
accumulated=0;
limit=5; #How many to process at the same time
while [ $i -lt $total_number_of_jobs ]
do
    while [ $accumulated -lt $limit ] && [ $i -lt $total_number_oj_jobs ]
    do
        ./${jobs[$i]} &
        (( i ++ ))
        (( accumulated ++ ))
    done
    wait
    accumulated=0

done
```

Let me know if it helps you. Regards!

Comment: `wc -l <list_of_jobs.txt` will keep the filename out of the list without any need for `awk`. That said, the bigger problem with this code is that `wait` doesn't guarantee that it waits for *only one* job. Thus, you start five jobs, you wait for all five to exit, then you start another five -- so each batch of five is bounded by the slowest of the five; from the point when the fastest of the five exits to when the slowest of the five does, you have wasted/unused resources.

Comment: Compare that to what `xargs -P "$limit"` will do, where you *always* have five jobs running at a time, starting another as soon as one exits.

Comment: In the first line what does "jobs" mean?  I understand list_of_jobs.txt is the input file, but I don't understand jobs.  Also, I'm researching xargs now...

Comment: Charles, do I put `"$5"` where you have `"$limit"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got your points they are all pretty valid. I did not know about the -P for xargs. nice.

Comment: @Emile, that code was assuming `limit=5`; if you want to hardcode it, just `xargs -P 5`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **GNU Parallel** as follows:

```
parallel -j 5 -a YourJobFile
```

There are lots of options, try adding `—-eta` or `—-progress`